# Validating then printing date input

Tags: javascript, date

I need to validate a date input so that it falls in between (including) 9/1/2016 and 8/31/2017. From this function, I'm trying to call a new function to print this date to the user. The following code seems to work, but calls the alert for (9/1/2016) and does not print the result using the Holiday() function.

```
function validate()
{

    var y= document.getElementById("userdate").value;
    var x= new Date(y);
    var minDate = new Date('09/01/2016');
    var maxDate =  new Date('08/31/2017');

    if (x >= minDate && x <= maxDate ){
         Holiday();
    }
    else{
        alert('Date must be between 9/1/2016 and 8/31/2017');
    }
 }

function Holiday() {

    var x = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
    var mydate = new Date(x);
    txt += "The date that user entered is " + mydate + "<p>";
    var day = mydate.getUTCDate();
    var month = mydate.getMonth() + 1; 
    var year = mydate.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Fomatted date " + month + "/" + day  + "/" + year;  
}
```

Comment: _"but calls the alert for (9/1/2016)"_ - no it doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/vo0axk10/

Comment: Questions to think about: Do all browsers work with a date string in that format passed to the `Date` constructor? What about time zones? Is there a reason to avoid modern conveniences and code JS like it's 1998?

Comment: Get the date once, not twice using two different methods.

Answer (score 0):

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zFmFYNOQodWX0DNqzQ9x?p=preview)

It seems to work fine for me

```
function validate() {
  //var y= document.getElementById("userdate").value; //COMMENTED OUT
  var x = new Date('09/01/2016');  //DEFAULT TO
  var minDate = new Date('09/01/2016');
  var maxDate = new Date('08/31/2017');
  debugger;
  if (x >= minDate && x <= maxDate) {
    Holiday(x);    // PASS THE VALUE
  } else {
    alert('Date must be between 9/1/2016 and 8/31/2017');
  }
}

function Holiday(theDate) {  //RECIEVE THE VALUE
  var mydate = theDate;
  var day = mydate.getUTCDate();
  var month = mydate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = mydate.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Fomatted date " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with this. It prints it to the screen, no alert. Give this a shot, even though I didn't change much.